# Breaking normalisation rules to accommodate scheduled tasks

Tags: database, database-design, scheduled-tasks

OK so this is quite a hard one to explain but I will do my best.

I have a table that contains information related to some customer hardware, some of this hardware is going to be subjected to scheduled monitoring, some every 24hrs and some at even shorter intervals (5-15min)

This monitoring is going to be done using some scheduled scripts and requires some totaling from another table which gathers data on the device.

What I am trying to figure out is, would I be better off just have the script scan through the entire table?

```
if 24hr enabled
    execute 24hr script
if instant enabled
    execute instant script
```

or would I be better off running a script that separates the hardware into 2 tables:

- 24hr enabled devices
- instant enabled devices

This would mean that the scheduled job would have less work to do, basically operate checks on every device in the table and finish.

This breaks normalisation rules as I would have duplicate data in certain tables, but as the tables are only populated from the source table I was thinking this might not be an issue.

Obviously I am quite unsure and this is the first time I have had to deal with such a complex system.

As example my table currently looks like (with addition of naming and set-up data)

- device_id
- alarm_high_value
- alarm_low_value
- enable_alarm_day
- enable_instant_alarms

I'm not sure if I have given enough information to help, so if anyone has any more questions please ask. Many Thanks

Comment: *"some totalling from another table"*. So you have 2 tables. Add the definitions of both and also what the script will be doing (pseudocode or the actual script). Will it be aggregating results from the instant-enabled devices?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following high level approach to separate the log collection data from the job creation and execution data

a) Collect the logging data in whatever format or tables you are doing so currently

b) Create a new table that contains the job execution data which is populated by analyzing the logging table. This can be done by a scheduled job. The job script runs off this table and also enables you to track the jobs that need to be done along with any feedback, errors etc